# update all cells in column based on user entry in any cell in that column

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a conversion table in Excel such that entering a value in any cell within a column will update all cells within that column with the appropriate converted value e.g. entering a value in B2 will update all other cells within that column, but equally, entering a value in B5 or B8 etc. will also do the same.

I assume that this will require some VBA coding but I am  not sufficiently capable in this to get this done. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks,
Ian

Comment: What is the update that needs to happen to the cells in column?

Comment: Initially I am looking to convert various pressure observations i.e. from bar to psi or Pa etc. I would like to be able to enter any value depending on what unit the observation is made in, and then convert this to any other pressure unit that I require.

For example cell B2 might be Bar. I would like to enter a vale in Bar and convert to the subsequent units further down the column. Equally I would like to be able to enter a value in hPa in, say, cell B6 and have the rest of the column convert.

Comment: Create a function that takes in a cell then converts it to the other pressure unit. Create a function that detects which pressure unit a cell is in. 
Use Gary's Student's code below for the Worksheet_Change and when a cell is changed, if it's in the right column, check which pressure unit it's in (2nd function) then convert it and all other cells in the row (using the 1st function) to the other unit type.

Answer (score 0):

Say the range of interest is **B1** through **B10**.  Place this event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range, v As Variant

    Set rng = Range("B1:B10")
    If Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    v = Target.Value
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        rng.Value = v
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

The code will take any value entered in any cell in the range of interest and apply it to the entire range.

Comment: Thanks! I shall give this a try. Do the various conversion factors need to be included within this script or are they entered in the cells in question?

Comment: @IanH  All the code does is to fill the range of interest based on entering a value in any cell in that range............you must do the rest.........

Comment: That's great, just wanted to clarify. Thanks for your help...will give this a go.

Answer (score 0):

please find the below code. you need to place this in worksheet code 
Assuming B1 to B50 is the target Address

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim enteredtext As Variant
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B1:B50")) Is Nothing Then
        enteredtext = Target.Value
        Range("B1:B50").Value = enteredtext
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! I shall give this a try as well.